# How to filter a numpy array based on two conditions: one depending on the other?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using the cv2 library to detect key points of 2 stereo images and converted the resulting dmatches objects to a numpy array:

```
kp_left, des_left = sift.detectAndCompute(im_left, mask_left)
matches = bf.match(des_left, des_right)  # according to assignment pdf
np_matches = dmatch2np(matches)
```

Then I want to filter matches if the key points are filtering, after y-direction, which should not differ bigger than 3 pixels:

```
ind = np.where(np.abs(kp_left[np_matches[:, 0], 1] - kp_right[np_matches[:, 1], 1]) < 4)
```

AND those key points should also not have a difference smaller than < 0. Then it means the key point is behind the camera.

```
ind = np.where((kp_left[np_matches[ind[0], 0], 0] - kp_right[np_matches[ind[0], 1], 0]) >= 0)
```

How to combine those 2 conditions?

Comment: Add sample cases for `np_matches`, `kp_left`, `kp_right`?

Comment: You could combine the two conditions by doing some boolean algebra. E.g. `A = np.arange(25); np.where((A>5)*(A<10))[0]` to find values greater than 5 AND smaller than 10. Here you'd use that only `True*True = True`. All the other multiplications result in `False`. It should be trivial to specialize this logical to your problem. *(A general remark: a more abstract question would trigger better answers. Your question has little to with cv2 and all that. It would be better to isolate your question)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general form is this:

```
condition1 = x < 4
condition2 = y >= 100
result = np.where(condition1 & condition2)
```

The even more general form:

```
conditions = [...] # list of bool arrays
result = np.where(np.logical_and.reduce(conditions))
```